# Crash when adding AKMicrophone

Tags: ios, avaudioengine, audiokit

I'm developing an audio app with AudioKit which involves periodically stopping AudioKit, rearranging or replacing the chain of `AKNode` subclasses, then restarting AudioKit. This has been working smoothly until I tried it with `AKMicrophone`.

If `AKMicrophone` is present in the initial sound chain, i.e., when I make the first call to `AudioKit.start(`), it works fine.  But if I put `AKMicrophone` into the sound chain at some point after an earlier call `AudioKit.start()`, the app will crash at the next `AudioKit.start()` call, producing the following error message:

```
...[avae] AVAudioEngine.mm:149:-[AVAudioEngine prepare]: Engine@0x1c0007170: could not initialize, error = -10875
...[mcmx] 338: input bus 0 sample rate is 0
...[avae] AVAEInternal.h:103:_AVAE_CheckNoErr: [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1266:Initialize: 
(err = AUGraphParser::InitializeActiveNodesInOutputChain(ThisGraph, kOutputChainOptimizedTraversal, *GetOutputNode(), isOutputChainActive)): error -10875
```

To illustrate, the following code runs smoothly:

```
    let mic = AKMicrophone()
    if let input = AudioKit.inputDevice {
        try! mic.setDevice(input)
    }
    AudioKit.output = mic
    AudioKit.start()
```

But if it is preceded by a call to `AudioKit.start()` it will crash:

```
    AudioKit.output = AKOscillator()
    AudioKit.start()
    AudioKit.stop()

    let mic = AKMicrophone()
    if let input = AudioKit.inputDevice {
        try! mic.setDevice(input)
    }
    AudioKit.output = mic
    AudioKit.start()
```

Is there any way to avoid this? Even help understanding the error message would be helpful.  Thanks.

Edit: I've noticed the same behaviour `AKStereoInput` - same error message under the same conditions

Answer (score 0):

After

```
AudioKit.output = AKOscillator()
AudioKit.start()
```

Try;

```
do{
   try AudioKit.stop()
   try AudioKit.shutdown()
   AudioKit.output = nil
}catch{
   print(error)
}
```